Error: "[plugin angular-browser-node-built-in] The package 'crypto' wasn't found on the file system" after updating to Angular 19
I recently updated my Angular project to version 19, and now I’m encountering the following error when building or serving the application:
[ERROR] The package "crypto" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. [plugin angular-browser-node-built-in]

node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:50:25:
  50 │         crypto = require('crypto');
      ╵                          ~~~~~~~~

I’m using the crypto-js library along with secure-web-storage to handle encrypted local storage in the browser.
Here’s how I import and use these libraries in my StorageService:
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';
import aes from 'crypto-js/aes';
import Utf8 from 'crypto-js/enc-utf8';

I’ve added the following configurations to try resolving the issue:
1- angular.json:
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
  "secure-web-storage",
  "crypto-js",
  "crypto"
]

2- tsconfig.json:
"paths": {
  "crypto": ["./node_modules/crypto-js"]
}


Facing the same issue with angular 19. Have you able to fix this?

The problem was you are using the imports as:
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';
import aes from 'crypto-js/aes';
import Utf8 from 'crypto-js/enc-utf8';

According to the crypto-js npm page. This method is meant for node.js, below is the process for using crypto-js for Angular 19:
Using  CryptoJS with Angular 19:
First install crypto-js types and package:
npm install crypto-js
npm i --save-dev @types/crypto-js

After this you can access the root object CryptoJS or the inner components like below.
import { AES } from 'crypto-js';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

Full Code:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AES } from 'crypto-js';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AESEncryptDecryptService {
  secretKey = 'YourSecretKeyForEncryption&Descryption';
  constructor() {}

  encrypt(value: string): string {
    return AES.encrypt(value, this.secretKey.trim()).toString();
  }

  decrypt(textToDecrypt: string) {
    return AES.decrypt(textToDecrypt, this.secretKey.trim()).toString(
      CryptoJS.enc.Utf8
    );
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: ``,
})
export class App {
  aesService = inject(AESEncryptDecryptService);
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.aesService.encrypt('asdf'));
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you! I tried, but the issue persists with the same error: "The package 'crypto' wasn't found on the file system but is built into Node."

@rami-sf updated my answer

I applied the changes, still same error seems issue from node.

@rami-sf if possible please replicate on stackblitz to check it

Have the same issue now after upgrading, have you solved it yet?

@Spock did my answer help you? the imports might be the problem?

Facing the same issue with angular 19. Have you able to fix this?

@RajanthaFernando if you could provide a stackblitz or github repo with the issue happening I can check and debug.

This problem is only in version 19.0.4
see GitHub issue 29099 and GitHub commit
